# Firebase rules with Bolt not allowing write of new blog post

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-authentication

I wish to create a blog using Firebase.

My rules are :

```
type Post {
    title: String,
    timestamp: Number,
    content: String
}

path / {
    write() {false}
    read() {true}

    /posts/{post} is Post {
        write() {isAdmin()}
    }
}

isAdmin() {auth != null && auth.uid == 'xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx'}
```

Reading posts works. But when I want to post one, it throws a `permission_denied`.

I'm successfully logged through the `authWithPassword` method and submit a post.

```
firebase.authWithPassword({email: 'myEmail@email.com', password: 'myPass'}).then(function(authData) {
  if (authData) {
    firebase.child('/articles').push().set(json);
  }
});
```

where `json` is equal to

```
{
  'title': 'My title',
  'timestamp': 89430867,
  'content': 'My Content'
}
```

How I can fix that error ?

Comment: Can you add the value of `json` into the question? It's probably also be useful to see how you authenticate and then write.

Comment: Thanks for adding the JSON, that seems to match the Bolt spec. Can you also show the flow from authentication to the `set()`? I suspect the mistake may be there.

Answer (score 0):

Finally,

I tried to submit a post from the simulator provided by Firebase. It worked. So, rules were fine.

I decided to compare websockets' frames of my website, and those of the simulator.

And I saw I made a mistake in my code. I was trying to send a string instead of an object.